# How can i use mysql in html/javascript with node.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, html

I have a node.js webserver working. And i can connect to my database, but i can't give my variable's to my html-page. I tried working with EJS but there i could only give a sentence (not a variable) to the page. is there a way to give a variable to the page or do query on de page (with JS maybe?)

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var path = require('path');
var string = require('string');

var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'website',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'TeamAwesome',
});



connection.connect(function(err) {
    console.log('Connection: Succeeded');
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
});






var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/',function(req, res)
{
    res.render('index.ejs');

});
app.get('/index.ejs',function(req, res)
{
    res.render('index.ejs');

});
app.get('/muziek.ejs',function(req, res)
{
    string ='';
    muziek = connection.query('SELECT * FROM Muziek', function(err, rows) {
    // connected! (unless `err` is set)
    string = '<tr><td><img height="150px" width="150px"/></td><td><p id="Artiest">';
    string = string + rows[0][1];
    string = string + '</p></td><td><p id="Titel">';
    string = string + rows[0][2];
    string = string + '</p></td></tr> ';

    });

    res.render('muziek.ejs',{

         music: string

    });
    console.log(string)
});



app.listen(8125);
console.log('Running @ localhost:8125');
```

muziek.ejs

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%- music %>


</body>
</html>
```

I don't get the string in my html-page.. 
Anyone who could help me?

Comment: I'm not familier with the library, but since `connection.query` takes a callback, I'm betting it is asynchronous and hasn't populated `string` by the time you call `render`

Comment: That would be it! I'm trying out socket.io now.. It does what i need but only when i try it local, the moment i host is it doesn't see/connect with de socket.io.js script